# Add a item to a navigation drawer

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I want to add a item to a navigation drawer programmatically. I use this xml for the navigation drawer:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group
    android:id="@+id/nav_group"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item1"
        android:title="@string/nav_text_item1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item2"
        android:title="@string/nav_text_item2" />
</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/nav_group2"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item  android:id="@+id/nav_menu" android:title="History">
        <menu>
           <!-- Add Items here-->
        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
<group
    android:id="@+id/nav_group3"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_item3"
            android:title="@string/nav_text_item3" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_item4"
            android:title="@string/nav_text_item4" />

</group>
```

I want to show the category "History" with no items at the beginning and then add items to the category later. But how do I do this? I can add items and Submenus to the end of the List but not in the middle. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I still use RecyclerView for Navigation Drawer. Customization is very easy then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Menu.addSubMenu** to create menu group and **Menu.add** to add menu item.

[android developer manual link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html)

```
NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.your_nav_view_id);
Menu m = navView.getMenu();
SubMenu menuGroup = m.addSubMenu("My menu group");
menuGroup .add("Foo");
menuGroup .add("Bar");
```

Or if you don't want to use menu group just add to the menu directly

```
NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.your_nav_view_id);
Menu m = navView.getMenu();
MenuItem foo_menu_item=m.add("foo");
```

Comment: findViewById(R.id.xx) returns null for me, did something change with the way menu layouts work?