# How to change drawer menu on fragment change

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments

I have bottom navigation to navigate between two fragments and a button for the side menu (drawer menu). My question is how to change the drawer menu based on fragments. When I switch to one fragment I want different side menu options.

Comment: Are you trying to use a navigation drawer to show destinations? or are you trying to use it more of a menu and show options?

Comment: Menu and show options

Comment: So, turns out I was incorrect, I thought that there was a difference between the navigation-drawer and a generic drawer, turns out there isn't really a difference. The reference for how to use DrawerLayout is under adding a navigation drawer, but this documentation doesn't appear to solve your problem. However, [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708462/add-a-item-to-a-navigation-drawer) should get you a solution.